# Perl import script- need to rename the daily file

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that was written by someone else. I deal more with PHP and JS. There is a daily file that is uploaded and then imported into our DB. The file name format is Alwaysthesamename_timestamp.txt

My question is can I either rename the file to Alwaysthesamename before the import occurs and then delete the file or does perl have a way to ignore the underscore and everything after it to import? Any direction is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You can modify the Perl script to open any file you want. You'll have to show us the code if you want help doing that, though. As it is, you don't provide enough details for your question to be answerable.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : I think the question is clear enough. A little lacking in research, but definitely useful and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, both approaches are equally doable.

1. **Rename the file**

   ```
   use File::Copy 'move';
   move( 'Alwaysthesamename_timestamp.txt', 'Alwaysthesamename.txt' )
     or die "Unable to rename log file: $!";
   ```
2. **Detect the file**

   Use Perl's [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function:

   ```
   my ( $file ) = glob( "Alwaysthesamename*" );
   ```

   ( Note that `glob "something"` could also be written as `<something>` )

   Of course, the more fun problem is when you have multiple such files in the same directory/location. If your timestamp is `YYYY-MM-DD` format, a simple string [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) should yield the latest file:

   ```
   my ( $file ) = reverse sort glob "Alwaysthesamename*";
   ```